# Is there a bulletproof concept to get h1 and p exact on one and the same (base)line?

Tags: css

See this page at > [www.tvdiever.nl](http://www.tvdiever.nl/test)

HTML:

```
<div id="slogan">
<h1 id="site-name"><span></span><txp:site_name /></h1>
<p id="site-slogan"><span></span><txp:site_slogan /></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* @fontface! */
/* all fine in all browsers mac or windows */
/* h1 and p have more or less the same baseline by giving h1 a line-height of 120% ... */

#slogan {
    height: 3.7em;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #220082;
    float: left;
    padding-top: .3em; /* to get h1 and p more or less in the middle of the box! */
}

h1#site-name {
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font: normal normal 2.8em/120% FontinSansRegular, 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif;
    display: inline !important;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    float: left;
}

p#site-slogan {
    color: #fff;
    font: normal normal 1.5em/2.8em FontinSansRegular, 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline !important;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    float: left;
}

/* end @fontface! */
```

Well ... it's working, after a lot of tweaking ... by giving h1 a line-height of 120% (!?), p a line-height of 2.8em, which is the font-size of h1 (that makes sense!) ... and of course give both elements display inline ...

The question is: is there a bulletproof method to bring h1 and p exact on the same (base)line whatever fontsize I give them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just display both elements (`H1`, `P`) as inline elements (`display: inline;`) - http://jsfiddle.net/Vss8E/

Comment: @redfox: that works, I presume, if you also use a [CSS Reset stylesheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-reset) to reduce the impacts of the different browser defaults. **Correction** it doesn't seem to make any difference: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Vss8E/1/ (note the un-checked 'Normalized CSS' on the left).

Comment: Because of your small example I left out float, vertical-align and line-height for both elements and that seems to be the bullet ... :)

Comment: @redfox: Remove useless `float`s, `vertical-align`s and margins and padding. You might want to apply a padding for the container - `div#slogan`. Then everything works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Bdc6g/